# Hi, i've got 3 switches in a daisy-chaining configuration, devices connected to them are disappearing after some days, any idea of what can get wrong?

Tags: switch

#### First Switch (Edimax GS-1005BE):

**Personal Computer:** 2.5 Gbit/s pci-e to ethernet card with jumbo frames 9000, OS: Windows 11
**Internet LAN Routeur:** 2.5 Gbit/s, Internet connection, some devices like TV, amplifier are connected on it by RJ-45.

#### Second Switch (Edimax GS-1005BE):

**Macbook Pro:** 1 Gbit/s
**Wifi box:** 1 Gbit/s

#### Third Switch

**Printer:** 1 Gbit/s
**NAS Synology:** 2.5 Gbit/s usb to ethernet adapter with jumbo frames 9000

I just need to switch off/on switches to see every device again.

I’ve added one device on the devices list (Wi-Fi repeater) on the second switch that I forgot to mention.

I never add or remove cable connected devices to the switches, config never changes. But because of wifi box, sometimes iPhones, laptops and others wifi devices are added or removed to the network !

When I lost visibility and access to the devices, it is only on the second and the third switches ! Sorry I didn’t mention it. I still see what is connected on the first switch and on the internet box receiver. Yes, some devices are also connected directly to it !

I tried to access from my PC connected on the first switch, and from my iPad through my WiFi box. From the first, as described before, there is no visibility at all of second and third floor devices. From iPad, I can’t access wifi box at all, it tries to get connection across wifi signal but it can’t. Probably because of the lost of connectivity on the second switch.

After some days of testing, it appears that jumbo frames isn’t the problem ! But I found something strange with my wifi repeater… In reality, it is an old wifi router that is used to be. And after disconnected my Nas and printer, the problem comes from it, WiFi signal is working, but no connection on it is possible. It’s only after turning off/on first switch that I can resolve the problem. Sometimes I need to restart the old WiFi router to resolve it.

Comment: What research have you done and what have you tried? Do all devices stop seeing each other? Or do some devices stop connecting? Do the lost devices still say that they have a connection? Are the devices that are lost the same devices each time? Please provide as much detail as you can, and use the EDIT button to add all this and more to the question itself.

Comment: If you are able, have you experimented with attaching all devices to the same switch?  If so, are the devices still discoverable under the same time-frame as to when they become disconnected in the current configuration. Might the MacBook and/or printer have a sleep setting that either puts the device or its network connection to sleep. If you haven't experimented with them on the same switch, I suggest doing so to see how the devices behave under the time-frame where they normally disconnect --- this could provide additional insights.

Comment: It’s difficult to connect all of them to the same switch because they are in different floors ! I’ve already think about sleep function, but sometime I loose connection after some hours, sometime after 6 days, with the same use of devices.

Comment: Mmmhh.Jumbo frames may be the issue. Try disabling those and see it that makes a difference. Many relatively cheap switches don't deal well with them even if they officially claim to support it. I have a similar Zyxel switch (same chipset on the inside) that is very stable (uptime 10 months, no issues), but I don't use jumbo-frames at all.

Comment: Ok i will try it ! Hope it’s not the problem because it speed up a lot.

Comment: After some days of testing, it appears that jumbo frames isn’t the problem ! But I found something strange with my wifi repeater… In reality, it is an old wifi router that is used to be. And after disconnected my Nas and printer, the problem comes from it, WiFi signal is working, but no connection on it is possible. It’s only after turning off/on first switch that I can resolve the problem. Sometimes I need to restart the old WiFi router to resolve it.

Comment: Ok, so after some long tests it appears that jumbo frames and WiFi repeater are not the problem at all. Even without them, I need to shut off / on the first switch after 2 days to make everything work !